# How do web applications bring the browser to foreground?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, web-applications

I've seen this behavior a lot especially with really annoying ads. They manage to bring the browser to the foreground even when you have it minimized or even when you are on another virtual desktop in windows 10. But what mechanisms are they using to get this to work?
I've been playing around and got it to work but really unreliably with a combination of alerts and notifications.
So how are the "professionals" doing it?
Don't worry I don't want to use this to create more annoying ads I just want to build a tool for myself that pops up to show me some important data.

I am by the way not necessarily looking for a clean or professional solution. It might very well be just a dirty hack as long as it works most of the time

Comment: You can only resize it if it is a pop up window. In that case you can use  yourWindow.resizeBy(width, height) or yourWindow.resizeTo(width, height)

Comment: @aleksa_95 Thanks, but I'm not talking about resizing a window. I'm talking about the complete browser popping into foreground over any other window or even making windows switch to the virtual desktop it resides on